# Missing winsxs from installation media

Tags: upgrade, windows-server-core

I have downloaded a media from msdn of windows server 2012 to upgrade a server core to gui, but this media does not have de *winsxs* folder in the *source* folder there is just a SXS folder.

I have tried to install the feature with this folder as a, path but is not working.

My question is what is the difference between the winsxs and the sxs folder and why is this folder missing from the installation media.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C:\Windows\WinSxS` is a folder in *installed systems*.
`\sources\sxs` is a folder in *installation media*.

When adding features to a running system asks for an installation source (f.e. when adding the .Net 3.5 framework), you should point it to the `\sources\sxs` folder on the installation media.

Nothing is missing here, the correct name for the folder in the installation media containing required setup files for additional features is exactly `\sources\sxs`.