# Server 2012 R2 - Features on Demand issue with powershell - Pulling roles/features from remote share

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, powershell, windows-server-core, unc

This is for learning/lab purposes.

-Two 2012 R2 servers. Server 1 is Standard GUI and server 2 is Server core. -Server 1 is updated, Server 2 is not updated at all with any windows updates -Workgroup environment, both static IPs in same subnet

I'm trying to create a feature file store for 2012 R2 roles/feature files so I can offload the installation files off of Server 2 (core install) until I actually need them. -The file store will sit on Server 1.

-So I copy roles/feature folder off of my 2012 R2 optical disk Sources\SxS folder to server 1's c: drive and I then share the folder with "Everyone" with read attributes and click share. -I verify the folder is actually being shared on the network via Network (file explorer) and net view/use on other machines.

I then go to server 2 and use this command to remove the binaries of a Role, for example: "Uninstall -WindowsFeature WINS -restart -remove" -Restart happens, then I verify that the binaries are no longer on the machine: Get-WindowsFeature WINS | where InstallState -eq removed

-I now attempt to Install the same role off of the features share folder on Server 1, which is shared with Everyone w/ read attrib. -I use command: "Install-WindowsFeature WINS -Source \server1\SxS -restart" and I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjQFL.png

-do I need to pass credentials? It's shared with everyone.. I can even open the folder remotely via file explorer on a workstation on same LAN. -I disabled firewall but no change

I appreciate any help on how to get this to work.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Using Features on Demand with Updated Systems and Patched Images](http://blogs.technet.com/b/server_core/archive/2012/11/05/using-features-on-demand-with-updated-systems-and-patched-images.aspx):

> That’s because `Install-WindowsFeature` uses the *machine account
>   credentials* – not your local user account credentials – to access the
>   installation source. If the installation source is located on a
>   network share, ensure that the *machine account* has permissions to
>   read from the network share.

Please read next article as well: [Cannot get Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra to install on Server Core](https://serverfault.com/q/496918/257436).

Comment: This is a workgroup environment. How is a machine account used at all if there is no domain authentication and how do I get one? (I remember reading this somewhere: "When a computer is joined to a domain, the computer is provisioned with a machine password.") 

I'm also wondering how one passes it to the remote share machine..